# Is it possible to run Matlab and Python in the same notebook?

Tags: python, r, matlab, jupyter-notebook

It is possible to run Python and R in the same notebook (see point 21 [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-shortcuts)). Is such a thing possible for Python and Matlab too?

Comment: There would be quite reasonable applications for Matlab and Python to be used in the same notebook. For example, if you want to write a notebook that explains differences between Matlab and Python syntax.